# Pandas groupby rolling mean with custom window size

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

### Problem definition:

For a Pandas DataFrame I'm trying to get a grouped by rolling mean with a changeable window size specified on each row that's relative to a date time index.

#### Example:

For the following `df` of weekly data:

```
| week_start_date | material | location | quantity | window_size |
|-----------------|----------|----------|----------|-------------|
| 2019-01-28      | C        | A        | 870      | 1           |
| 2019-02-04      | C        | A        | 920      | 3           |
| 2019-02-18      | C        | A        | 120      | 1           |
| 2019-02-25      | C        | A        | 120      | 2           |
| 2019-03-04      | C        | A        | 120      | 1           |
| 2018-12-31      | D        | A        | 1200     | 8           |
| 2019-01-21      | D        | A        | 720      | 8           |
| 2019-01-28      | D        | A        | 480      | 8           |
| 2019-02-04      | D        | A        | 600      | 8           |
| 2019-02-11      | D        | A        | 720      | 8           |
| 2019-02-18      | D        | A        | 80       | 8           |
| 2019-02-25      | D        | A        | 600      | 8           |
| 2019-03-04      | D        | A        | 1200     | 8           |
| 2019-01-14      | E        | B        | 150      | 1           |
| 2019-01-28      | E        | B        | 1416     | 1           |
| 2019-02-04      | F        | B        | 1164     | 1           |
| 2019-01-28      | G        | B        | 11520    | 8           |
```

The window needs to be relative to the actual date set in `week_start_date`, rather than treating it like an integer index.

It needs to be grouped by `material` and `location`.

The rolling mean is for column `quantity`.

The window size needs to vary/change based on the value in the `window_size` column. This value changes over time - it represents the number of weeks back in time that quantity needs to be aggregated for.

When a row isn't available, the mean should assume that value is 0, i.e.:
when a week-dated row isn't available
`mean(null, null, null, 1000) = 1000`
but it should actually:
mean(0,0,0,1000)=250
However - this should only apply after the first observation has been measured.

### Fixed window, relative to date column:

I can get a static window of 8 weeks (56 days) using the following:

```
df.set_index('week_start_date').groupby(['material', 'location'])['quantity'].rolling('56D', min_periods=1).mean()
```

I've explored use of [expanding](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) but haven't been successful.

How can the window size be set relative to each row it reads?

### Sample Data:

```
# Example Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'week_start_date': ['2019-01-28','2019-02-04','2019-02-18','2019-02-25','2019-03-04','2018-12-31','2019-01-21','2019-01-28','2019-02-04','2019-02-11','2019-02-18','2019-02-25','2019-03-04','2019-01-14','2019-01-28','2019-02-04','2019-01-28'],
'material': ['C','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','E','E','F','G'],
'location': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
'quantity': ['870','920','120','120','120','1200','720','480','600','720','80','600','1200','150','1416','1164','11520'],
'min_of_pdt_or_8_weeks': ['1','3','1','2','1','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','8','1','3','1','8']})
# Fix formats
df['week_start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['week_start_date'])
df['actual_week_qty'] = df['quantity'].astype(float)
```

### Expected result:

```
| material | location | week_start_date | quantity | 
| C        | A        | 2019-01-28      | 870      | 
| C        | A        | 2019-04-02      | 306.6667 | 
| C        | A        | 2019-02-18      | 520      | 
| C        | A        | 2019-02-25      | 386.6667 | 
| D        | A        | 2018-12-31      | 1200     | 
| D        | A        | 2019-01-21      | 960      | 
| D        | A        | 2019-01-28      | 800      | 
| D        | A        | 2019-04-02      | 600      | 
| D        | A        | 2019-11-02      | 720      | 
| D        | A        | 2019-02-18      | 400      | 
| D        | A        | 2019-02-25      | 466.6667 | 
| D        | A        | 2019-04-03      | 650      | 
| E        | B        | 2019-01-14      | 150      | 
| E        | B        | 2019-01-28      | 783      | 
| F        | B        | 2019-04-02      | 1164     | 
| G        | B        | 2019-01-28      | 11520    |
```

Comment: Can you show an expected output?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Added expected result to post.

Comment: Why second line is 920?

Comment: @QuangHoang 920 because the window_size is 3, but there isn't data for the 3 weeks before 02/04/2019

Comment: @credibly-close-mean "there isn't data" why shouldn't it count as 0? So the equivalent "slow code" is to do 8 different calculations (one for each 1w, 2w, ..., 8w rolling window) and then merge on window_size (Note: fillna of window_size NaN -> 8 should be done first, it's kinda noise here). Is your real example actually 1-8? I am slightly skeptical how easy it is to beat the 8 calcs + join. Also, is actual_week_qty col the same as quantity? I have a solution with that... though I think there;s a small issue with the silly English date format (please use the canonical iso one for the love of!)

Comment: @AndyHayden great points - original question updated:
- dates now canonoical
- fixed the column name in the example formulae

When a row isn't available, the mean should assume that value is 0, i.e.:
when a week-dated row isn't available
`mean(null, null, null, 1000) = 1000`
but it should actually:
mean(0,0,0,1000)=250
However - this should only apply after the first observation has been measured to avoid the new entries having erroneous values for their first N entries.

Yes it's hard capped at 8 potential options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive way you might do this, is to do the 8 (assuming this is bounded!) calculations and merge the results:

```
In [11]: d = {w: df.set_index('week_start_date')
                   .groupby(['material', 'location'])['quantity']
                   .rolling(f'{7*w}D', min_periods=1)
                   .mean()
                   .reset_index(name="mean")
                   .assign(window_size=w)
              for w in range(1, 9)}
```

then you can concat these DataFrames together and merge with the original, since we have the window_size column in both left and right it'll inner on that.

```
In [12]: pd.concat(d.values()).merge(df, how="inner")
Out[12]:
   material location week_start_date          mean  window_size  quantity
0         C        A      2019-01-28    870.000000            1     870.0
1         C        A      2019-02-18    520.000000            1     120.0
2         C        A      2019-04-03    320.000000            1     120.0
3         E        B      2019-01-14    150.000000            1     150.0
4         F        B      2019-04-02   1164.000000            1    1164.0
5         C        A      2019-02-25    386.666667            2     120.0
6         C        A      2019-04-02    920.000000            3     920.0
7         E        B      2019-01-28    783.000000            3    1416.0
8         D        A      2018-12-31   1200.000000            8    1200.0
9         D        A      2019-01-21    960.000000            8     720.0
10        D        A      2019-01-28    800.000000            8     480.0
11        D        A      2019-04-02    600.000000            8     600.0
12        D        A      2019-11-02    720.000000            8     720.0
13        D        A      2019-02-18    400.000000            8      80.0
14        D        A      2019-02-25    466.666667            8     600.0
15        D        A      2019-04-03    650.000000            8    1200.0
16        G        B      2019-01-28  11520.000000            8   11520.0
```

Note: This assumes you've set the fillna of window_size to 8:

```
df.window_size = df.window_size.replace('NaN', 8).astype(int)  # in your example
```

Further, you want to ensure you pass format to to_datetime to ensure you don't hit ambiguity, pandas *may* be able to do a good job here in infering it... but I wouldn't rely on it (use explicitly `format='%d/%m/%Y`). You want to get rid of the weird date formats as soon as you read it in, this can also be passed in read_csv (dayfirst=True) and friends.

---

I'm not entirely convinced this is what you want, since there is a difference between your input df and expected (e.g. there's no G B in the expected...).

Regardless, I suspect there is a single shoot way to do this, *but* it will depend on the sparsity of the week/material/location (if it's dense it'll be much easier, if it's sparse this may be the best bet)...
Now I think about it, you can do this completely on the material/location subDataFrame, can you simplify this problem to just be a function of that DataFrame (just week+value ignoring material/location) or will that apply be too slow?